# Netbeans 8.0.2 + Glassfish server 4.1

Tags: java, netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

Whenever I run my project from Netbeans, I get this error:

```
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here is the log output:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform 
Oct 30, 2015 3:54:15 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner 
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner. 
Oct 30, 2015 3:54:15 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations 
WARNING: Skipping entry because it is not an absolute URI. 
Oct 30, 2015 3:54:15 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations 
WARNING: Skipping entry because it is not an absolute URI. 
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@2b936ab9 in service registry. 
Found populator: com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml 
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C: \Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish 
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C: \Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates 
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C: \Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties 
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C: \Users\Jimmyzz\personal_domain1\config\logging.properties 
Info: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 (build 13) 
Info: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter 
Info: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created. 
Info: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created. 
Info: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created. 
Info: Authorization Service has successfully initialized. 
Info: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry 
Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 58ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080] 
Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181] 
Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 7ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848] 
Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700] 
Info: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 (13) startup time : Felix (1,408ms), startup services(571ms), total(1,979ms) 
Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: Ems - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676] 
Info: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@55f8669d as 0511 service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@769d513. 
Info: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on 3MXService URL service:jmx:rmi://100.75.255.36:8686/jndi/rmi://100.75.255.36:8686/jmxrmi 
Info: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Fina1 
Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 8ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181] 
Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 9ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]I
```

Comment: Could you give more context about your problem? what have you done? What specific problems have you had? What is your test case?

Comment: In the "output" window you should see a tab for Glassfish which holds the server log output. Is there any error in there?

Comment: i tried deleting re-adding glassfish, uninstall install netbeans,checked that the database username pass are correct with the program,tried different projects(student so we have some example projects ready to run just by creating a DB and running) but still same
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
D:\etc\etc\etc\example3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1048: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @Gimby :WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.

Comment: Rather than posting a single line, try adding the server log output to your question by editing it in.

Comment: added as image if it helps :)

Comment: You forgot to ping me so I didn't see. Unfortunately the posted log output contains no hint of a deployment failure, so there really is nothing to see. Its just the log you would get when you start the server with absolutely no deployed application. Try starting the server and then "running" the application to trigger netbeans to try and redeploy the application, then see what log output that might add.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has a similar problem mine got fixed by renaming my project folder,
without spaces or symbols (eg. instead of 'Netbeans project & beans' to NetbeansProjectNBeans).